# Adding labels from a file to data points on a plot

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have loaded x and y data from a csv file and plotted it. I have loaded the name of each point from the csv file but am having trouble attaching this as a label to each point on the plot.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('plotfile.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=str,skiprows=1)
data2 = np.genfromtxt('plotfile.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=float,skiprows=1)
x = data2[:,1]
y = data2[:,3]
z = data[:,2]

pylab.xlabel("Distance (km)")
pylab.ylabel("Precursor Length (s)")

scatter(x,y)
text(x,y,labels=z, pos=3)
```

I am not sure whether I should use the annotate command instead of text. I am currently getting an error saying:

TypeError: text() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `text()`, `x`, `y` have to be scalars (see docstring), not `array`-like. So the following is a workaround:

```
x=[0.3,0.5]
y=[0.3,0.5]
z=['ok','no']
map(text,x,y,z)
```

[image]

The reason you are getting exception is that you didn't provide the required argument `s` for `text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

May be text() does not recognize labels. Try this

```
text(x, y, z)
```

Comment: This then gives me a very large error about saving the figure - I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: This text() function is for pylab module i.e. pylab.text(). Which text function are you using anyway ...